# Autenticación al SIFEN con PHP para Facturación Electrónica Paraguay PY

Tags: php, sifen

Estamos intentando autenticarnos al SIFEN (Paraguay) utilizando SoapClient (PHP) y el Certificado PFX válido obtenido desde un PSC autorizado, pero tenemos algunas dudas sobre el proceso de autenticación. Todo esto en el entorno de testo de SIFEN, inicialmente.

No identificamos en el manual técnico como utilizar el idCSC y el CSC, es decir no sabemos si utilizar estos datos al firmar o tenemos que enviarlos en la petición del SoapClient, por ejemplo.

Estamos generando y firmando un XML, entendemos correctamente y estamos intentando llamar el recurso https://sifen-test.set.gov.py/de/ws/consultas/consulta-ruc.wsdl?wsdl, pero sin éxito. Tenemos una denegación de servidor obteniendo el siguiente mensaje directamente al instanciar el SoapClient:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://sifen-test.set.gov.py/de/ws/consultas/consulta-ruc.wsdl?WSDL' : Premature end of data in tag td

Entendemos que tiene que ver con el proceso de autenticación al SIFEN, pero no estamos pudiendo resolverlo.

Si alguien tiene algún dato que pueda llegar a ser útil sobre el proceso de autenticación, estaríamos desde ya mas que agradecidos.

Saludos!

Comment: yo cobro por eso XD